# Simple Raw Packet Capture & Send Program

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, packet, sniffer

I would like to create a demo with the following topology:

... --->[switch] <---> [Host]

**DEMO**: A switch sends a packet to a monitoring Host (The packets original destination is not this Host, yet switch will send to it via a mirror port).  The monitor-Host is to capture that packet, do something with it (e.g., just dump the L2-L4 header fields into some log file), and then send the original packet back towards the switch.

**Host Environment:** Ubuntu 12.04 Linux.

**Dilemma:** What's the simplest way I can capture the packet in Host and send back the original packet to the switch?

**Possibilities to Explore:**

- Create a packet sniffer program in C (looks complex ... libpcap, AF_Packet  sockets etc.).
- Try to use python scapy (don't know how complex this will be).
- Try to install some open source proxy server of some kind to which I can write a plugin that will examine the captured packets.

**Question**: Any better recommendations (if I can avoid going the programming route, it would be preferred. Is there any simple scripting method to do this?).  Looking for a quick-and-dirty method here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

well, you can use packets sniffers available such as wireshark, ettercap which will capture all network packets (using promisc mode) and dump them in readable format. 
Or, you can preety much easily code sniffer for yourself in python, linux which is not so much complex to understand..